# Error in iterator declaration for std::map

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

Declaration works when I declare an iterator like this:

```
map<string,int>::iterator it, temp;
```

Why doesn't the following work too?

```
map<string,int>temp, ::iterator it;
```

> error: expected initializer before 'it'

Why is this causing an error?

Comment: Because it's not valid C++. You can't just write like you want, you have to follow the rules of the language.

Comment: Isn't both declaration looks alike ?

Comment: Why is this down vote ??
Is the question totally illogical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterator` is a member type inside `std::map` container, to have a variable of this type you need to use the proper syntax, `map<string,int>temp, ::iterator it;` is simply wrong as complained by the compiler.

*`map<string,int>::iterator`* is a type, *`::iterator`* is ill formed.

Comment: I didn't know that map<string,int>::iterator is a type :(

Comment: @AliAkber Its okay, now you know it

Comment: is the question totally illogical ?
I'm wondering why i received these down vote ?
Or people just do this as fun ?

Comment: @AliAkber No its not illogical, but surely it didn't show any search efforts, there are several similar questions on StackOverflow, please do a search.

Comment: Obviously I searched..
but i didn't find these type of error or question :(
May be i'm not good at searching :(

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are creating two iterators for the stl map. In the second case you are creating stl maps and c++ expects no space in the identifier and identifier should not start with  ":" symbol (rules of c++ lang).

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't aware of the fact